# See vip for each class in multi-class randomforest?

Tags: r, tidymodels

In this example of multi-class classification using randomforest model, the author creates a vip chart as shown below. Is there a way to view which variables are influencing the model to predict each of the response categories? For example, I'd like to be able to see that "x" variable is driving something to be classified as "x" volcano type (response category).

https://juliasilge.com/blog/multinomial-volcano-eruptions/

```
library(vip)

rf_spec %>%
  set_engine("ranger", importance = "permutation") %>%
  fit(
    volcano_type ~ .,
    data = juice(volcano_prep) %>%
      select(-volcano_number) %>%
      janitor::clean_names()
  ) %>%
  vip(geom = "point")
```

Comment: This variable importance measure for random forest models works by observing how model accuracy/RMSE/etc changes after randomly permuting or shuffling each predictor variable. This doesn't give any info on different outcome categories, just overall info. You [probably want to use a different explainability option](https://www.tmwr.org/explain.html).

Comment: Thank you, Julia! I have read the section on "explaining models and predictions." Is one way to go about it to use the methods for local explanations on three select datapoints -- one for each of my different outcome categories?

Comment: Check out [this DALEX vignette](https://modeloriented.github.io/DALEX/articles/multilabel_classification.html) on multiclass classification.

Comment: What units do the shapley additive explanations take (contribution values in some of the charts)? In this case, it's a random forest with nominal features, so I'm trying to wrap my head around what this value represents exactly in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created an explainer using `explain_tidymodels`, then used the `DALEX vignette`.

https://www.tmwr.org/explain.html
https://modeloriented.github.io/DALEX/articles/multilabel_classification.html